# Have more than 400 000, repopulating the DB takes 5 hours

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scale

Simply running

```
ElectricityProfile.find_each do |ep|
  if UserProfile.exists?(ep.owner_id) && ep.owner_type == 'UserProfile'
    ElectricityProfileSummary.create(ep)
  end
end
```

Takes ages (5 hours) to populate the table. Is there any better way to populate the DB?

Lets say get all the data from the DB and store it in array, hash, etc and then push to create a DB

```
ElectricityProfile.find_each do |ep|
  if UserProfile.exists?(ep.owner_id) && ep.owner_type == 'UserProfile'
    array_of_electricity_profiles.push(ep)
  end
end
ElectricityProfileSummary.mass_create(ep) # => or any other method :)
```

Sorry forgot mention I do have overridden method `create`, that takes multiple models and creates ElectricityProfileSummary...

```
create!(:owner_id => electricity_profile.owner_id,
        :owner_type => electricity_profile.owner_type,
        :property_type => electricity_profile.owner.user_property_type,
        :household_size => electricity_profile.owner.user_num_of_people,
        :has_swimming_pool => electricity_profile.has_swimming_pool,
        :bill => electricity_bill,
        :contract => electricity_profile.on_contract,
        :dirty => true,
        :provider => electricity_profile.supplier_id,
        :plan => electricity_profile.plan_id,
        :state => state,
        :postcode => postcode,
        :discount => discount,
        :has_air_conditioner => electricity_profile.has_air_conditioner,
        :has_electric_hot_water => electricity_profile.has_electric_hot_water,
        :has_electric_central_heating => electricity_profile.has_electric_central_heating,
        :has_electric_cooktup => electricity_profile.has_electric_cooktup
)
```

Comment: you can consider batch fetching and batch insert. check http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/ for the later.

Comment: Have you tried the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) gem?

Comment: @pjumble, had a look at that one, unfortunately I do have overridden create method for the model. And I can't use update with activerecord-import

Comment: Can you get ActiveRecord out of the way completely and just send a bunch of SQL into the database? Or use the database's dump/restore tools? AR isn't exactly quick, especially for bulk operations.

Comment: Given the task you're describing, and the fact that there's logic and possible record creation in each of 400k runs, 5 hours doesn't sound like very long to me. I don't think there's a better way to write your code using AR, to speed up the process you probably need to work directly on the database. That said, in my experience 5 hours isn't an astronomical length of time for a massive modification to a database of this size. You're not running this task every day are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in a stored procedure or raw SQL would probably be the best way to go since ActiveRecord can be very expensive when dealing with that many records.  However, you can speed it up quite a bit by using `includes` or `joins`.

It looks like you only want to create ElectricityProfileSummary models.  I am a little unsure of how your relationships look, but assuming you have the following:

```
class ElectricityProfile
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class UserProfile
  has_many :electricity_profiles, as: owner
end
```

... you should be able to do something like this:

```
ElectricityProfile.includes(:owner).each do |ep|
  ElectricityProfileSummary.create(ep)
end
```

Now, I am basing this on the assumption that you are using a polymorphic relationship between ElectricityProfile and UserProfile.  If that is not the case, let me know.  (I made the assumption because you have `owner_id` and `owner_type`, which as a pair make up the two fields necessary for polymorphic relationships.)

Why is using an includes better?  Using includes causes ActiveRecord to eager load the relationship between the two models, so you're not doing n+1 queries like you are now.  Actually, because you are creating records based on the number of ElectricityProfile records, you're still doing n+1, but what you are doing now is more expensive than n+1 because you are querying UserProfile for every single ElectricityProfile, and then you are querying UserProfile again when creating the ElectricityProfileSummary because you are lazy loading the relationship between EP and UP.

When you do includes, Rails will use an inner join to query between the two tables.  Using an inner join eliminates the necessity to do ensure that the UserProfile exists, since the inner join will only return records where both sides of the relationship exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you could wrap your import loop into one transaction block, it should speed up import immensely. Read on about ROR transactions [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Sweet mate, let me have a look at this solutions as it seems to solve my issue

Comment: How would a transaction speed up this query?  I do not understand.

Comment: Without transactions, every insert is auto-committed - database ensures that data is flushed to disk, which is very slow. With transactions, it only must ensure that whole transaction is flushed, and need not to worry about every single insert being flushed. It is not uncommon to have 100x-1000x speedup because of this

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  I think combining your answer with mine would be the way to go.

Comment: whichever helped most, I guess :-)